# IPSec-Tools build on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ipsec

I am trying to build ipsec-tools package from http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net/ on Ubuntu PC.
I build the package with:

```
$ ./autoreconf --force --install
$ ./bootstrap
$ ./configure --enable-security-context=no
$ make
```

The make stops with the following error message:

```
grabmyaddr.c:424: error: dereferencing pointer ‘sin6’ does break strict-aliasing rules
```

Any idea how to finish the make without errors?

Comment: It's a programming error on the part of the developers. If you have a little C experience, then check out [this](http://blog.worldofcoding.com/2010/02/solving-gcc-44-strict-aliasing-problems.html) - it was the first Google result. Or, report this bug and somebody should get around to it as compile errors tend to be pretty high priority.

Answer (score 3):

it is caused by the new strict aliasing checking in the 4.4 version of gcc. You can fix it by changing in the general Makefile and in the src/racoon subdirectory Makefile the CFLAGS line to include also -fno-strict-aliasing.

Comment: You can also do `export CFLAGS="-fno-strict-aliasing"` before `configure` and `make`, that way the flag is taken into account without changing the Makefiles.